# Imprimir Conteúdo que Tenha Vários Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Estou fazendo um site no qual se tem um quadro para colorir um desenho.

Depois de muita pesquisa consegui fazer um esquema de pintar uma determinada área do desenho do `canvas`.

Agora eu quero fazer uma função que imprima o desenho que eu fiz.

Estou tentando fazer assim:

```
<div id="painter">
<canvas style="z-index: 1;"></canvas>
<canvas style="z-index: 2;"></canvas>
<canvas style="z-index: 3;"></canvas>
<canvas style="z-index: 4;"></canvas>
</div>
```

Meu quadro tem todos estes `canvas`.

Quando eu faço um risco no quadro ele cria outro `canvas` e assim sucessivamente.

Quero imprimir o desenho, mas dessa forma não está indo. Quando abre a tela para imprimir aparece 5 folhas vazias.

O `canvas` não sai na impressão ?

Comment: Consegui. Não foi tão difícil. Pesquisei um pouco no SOen.

Comment: que bom que resolveu! Poste como resposta a sua solução para que ajude outras pessoas que possam ter o mesmo problema ;)

Comment: Vou postar. Estava esperando dar um tempo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontrei a resposta no SOen.

```
    $("#printImagem").on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var Can = new Array();
        $('canvas').each(function(index, el){
            Can[index] = $(el)[0].toDataURL('image/png');
        });

        var windowContent = '<!DOCTYPE html>';
        windowContent += '<head><title>Imprimir Desenho</title></head>';
        windowContent += '<body>';

        for(var x = 0; x <= Can.length - 1; x++)
            windowContent += '<img src = "' + Can[x] + '" style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0;">';

        windowContent += '</body>';
        windowContent += '</html>';
        var printWin = window.open('', '', width = 340, height = 260);
        printWin.document.open();
        printWin.document.write(windowContent);
        printWin.document.close();
        printWin.focus();
        printWin.print();
    });
```

A única coisa que me serviu foi o `toDataURL`. Não sabia que tinha que fazer isso para transformar o `canvas` numa imagem. Na verdade ela é convertida em `base64` e `png`, conforme defini no parâmetro da função `toDataURL('image/png')`.

Mas pode ser que tenha mais de um `canvas` na área de desenho.

Então eu fiz um `each` pesquisando cada `canvas` e o convertendo em `base64` e o colocando na mesma posição com `absolute`, `top` e `left` com valor `0`.

Para isso usei um `array`. Não sei se existe maneiras melhor de fazer. Se existir, por favor postem a lógica. Me refiro ao `array` e ao `each`.